# Grouping together related sets

Tags: algorithm, set

I have a set S consisting of N sets, each containing 2 or more numbers. E.g.:

S={{1,2,6},{6,3,4,2},{6,2},{1,9,12},{7,8,12}}. So, here N=5

The question is: Determine which sets should be grouped together, depending on how many identical numbers they have. If, for instance, a set is a subset of a larger set (e.g. the second and third set in the example), then we would want that those are grouped together. However, also if there is a reasonable correlation between sets, we would want to group them together.

The total number of groups is given (P). The sizes of the groups are on average N/P, but they may vary.

I think there is probably a standard algorithm to tackle this problem, can anyone help me finding it? Thanks!

Comment: For the sets S={{1}, {2}, {1,2}}, would we want to group all three together (as {1} and {2} are both subsets of {1,2}), even though {1} and {2} are themselves completely distinct?

Comment: Each set in S contains at least 2 elements. Besides, those trivial cases arent very important. Also, yes: In the example you gave it would be correct to group them all in the same group provided P=1. However, generally both N and P are much bigger so those trivial cases arent an issue.

Comment: Well, then what about the first three sets in your example? {6, 2} is a subset of {6, 3, 4, 2} and {6, 2} and {1, 2, 6} have a "reasonable corelation".

Comment: In that case, we could pick any.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an untested idea:

Create a graph with the sets as vertices and with the [Jaccard index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) (*A*∩*B*) / (*A*∪*B*) as edge weight between sets *A* and *B*. Vertices with disjoint sets (and Jaccard index 0) are not connected.

Then use a clustering algorithm to divide the graph into clusters, where edges with a low weight are cut, so that you get [*P* disjoint subgraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut). [Correlation clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_clustering) might also be an approach, although you can't control the number of groups, but you could guess a threshold similarity.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you are looking for is named k-means. It's an iterative  algorithm that converges N points into k predefined sets. The convergence may be stopped earlier, if you set a threshold for the number of iterations. In any cases, it stops when a state (p - 1) yielded the same sets of the current state (p).

In your case, you have `k = P` predefined points (a.k.a. centroids). Each of the N points in your dataset is a set itself. To put points together in a single cluster, k-means requires a similarity metric. That means you have to provide a function that, given two points from the data base, tells how similar they are.

As pointed by @MOehm, Jaccard index is a nice metric to evaluate the similarity in between sets. In general, as long as you decide which similarity metric to use, any clustering algorithm that allows use to set the number of final clusters is a solution.